# Will StackExchange sites be part of Federated Fluther?

Tags: discussion, seo, third-party

It looks like Fluther is trying to make a Q&A site aggregator (See [Fluther's website](http://www.fluther.com/federated/) and [TechCrunch post on it](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/09/federated-fluther-lets-third-parties-integrate-qa-with-a-few-lines-of-code/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+Techcrunch+(TechCrunch))). It claims to drive more traffic to sites that partner with it. Has SE looked into partnering with them? Are we already?

Comment: What's better than finding an answer to your question at the top of a Google search? Finding what appears to be an answer embedded in an ad-clogged link farm requiring you to shake off all manner of frames and redirects before finally taking you to the site that would otherwise have come out on top...

Comment: I don't see a point in partnering here. If anything, SO might start a similar scheme. (Whether that would make sense is a different question.)

Comment: @Shog9 While agree that we would probably come up on top in SO, SU, and SF questions, that may not be true for some some of the newer SE sites coming out of Area51. For those sites this might be better than Google's page 2.

Comment: FWIW I'd never heard of Fluther until I read this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluther's Federated offering doesn't seem focused on being a cross QA aggregator--it's a way to embed their QA engine into externally hosted (and putatively public) sites. The aggregation is of embedded Fluther Federated QA content back into Fluther.com.

Simple analogy: if you could embed a small version of SE into your own site and then have that content rolled up into SE.

Federated isn't aggregating Yahoo! Answers, SE, Quora, etc. That exercise is left to some startup already out there working on that and getting it's YC application ready... ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. I often see SO results in Google, indicating the popularity and technical expertise of SO. But I've never once seen Fluther in those results.